# Insert into Database not working due to Relations in Database

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I've been trying to make an insert into the database whenever a user register, but I always got an SQL[23000] error and I realized that inside my database, there was a relationship to a different table and that is why I was getting an error. I'm used to creating a model and crud through Gii but this is the first time where I encountered an error because of relationships between tables. I think the problem is that I need to be able to insert into two models and I'm not completely sure how I should do that.

First things first, I'll show my schema:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `system_users` (
  `party_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `date_last_login` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `status` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Pending for Approval',
  `date_created` datetime NOT NULL,
  `date_modified` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `user_role` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `isLogin` int(1) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`party_id`)
  ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=219 ;

--
-- Constraints for dumped tables
--

--
-- Constraints for table `system_users`
--
ALTER TABLE `system_users`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `system_users_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`party_id`) REFERENCES `parties` (`id`);

 ---------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `parties` (
   `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `party_type_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
   KEY `party_type_id` (`party_type_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=200 ;

--
-- Constraints for dumped tables
--

--
-- Constraints for table `parties`
--
ALTER TABLE `parties`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `parties_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`party_type_id`) REFERENCES `party_types` (`id`);
```

After this, I generated a model using Gii and I called it SystemUsers.php and I also generated the crud into the systemUsers under view.

Now problem is, every time I select "Create," it throws me an error that it cannot somehow find the parties id.

Just in case, here is the code of my model SystemUsers.php:

```
<?php

class SystemUsers extends CActiveRecord
 {
/**
 * Returns the static model of the specified AR class.
 * @param string $className active record class name.
 * @return SystemUsers the static model class
 */
public static function model($className=__CLASS__)
{
    return parent::model($className);
}

/**
 * @return string the associated database table name
 */
public function tableName()
{
    return 'system_users';
}

/**
 * @return array validation rules for model attributes.
 */
public function rules()
{
    // NOTE: you should only define rules for those attributes that
    // will receive user inputs.
    return array(
        array('username, password, date_last_login, date_created, user_role, isLogin', 'required'),
        array('isLogin', 'numerical', 'integerOnly'=>true),
        array('username', 'length', 'max'=>200),
        array('password, user_role', 'length', 'max'=>255),
        array('status', 'length', 'max'=>50),
        array('date_modified', 'safe'),
        // The following rule is used by search().
        // Please remove those attributes that should not be searched.
        array('party_id, username, password, date_last_login, status, date_created, date_modified, user_role, isLogin', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),
    );
}

/**
 * @return array relational rules.
 */
public function relations()
{
    // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
    // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
    return array(
        'party_id' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'system_users', 'party_id'),
        'party_id' => array(self::HAS_ONE, 'parties', 'id'),

    );
}

/**
 * @return array customized attribute labels (name=>label)
 */
public function attributeLabels()
{
    return array(
        'party_id' => 'Party',
        'username' => 'Username',
        'password' => 'Password',
        'date_last_login' => 'Date Last Login',
        'status' => 'Status',
        'date_created' => 'Date Created',
        'date_modified' => 'Date Modified',
        'user_role' => 'User Role',
        'isLogin' => 'Is Login',
    );
}

/**
 * Retrieves a list of models based on the current search/filter conditions.
 * @return CActiveDataProvider the data provider that can return the models based on the search/filter conditions.
 */
public function search()
{
    // Warning: Please modify the following code to remove attributes that
    // should not be searched.

    $criteria=new CDbCriteria;

    $criteria->compare('party_id',$this->party_id,true);
    $criteria->compare('username',$this->username,true);
    $criteria->compare('password',$this->password,true);
    $criteria->compare('date_last_login',$this->date_last_login,true);
    $criteria->compare('status',$this->status,true);
    $criteria->compare('date_created',$this->date_created,true);
    $criteria->compare('date_modified',$this->date_modified,true);
    $criteria->compare('user_role',$this->user_role,true);
    $criteria->compare('isLogin',$this->isLogin);

    return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
        'criteria'=>$criteria,
    ));
}
}
```

Comment: Downvoted for posting duplicate requests : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21423325/sql-not-inserting-into-table-with-relation-in-yii

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as u have foreign key Constraints then you have have entry in parent table

```
system_users -> depends on parties
 and 
parties -> depends on party_types
```

so to insert the record in **system_user** you must have a record in **Parites** and similarly to insert the record in **parties** you must have a record in **party_types**

so first insert the record in **party_type** and for that party_type create record in **Parties** and then for that **party_id** create the record in **system_user**

Comment: I want to do this under one Controller. How would I be able to do this since obviously this deals with the Parties Controller

Comment: u r right for that u have to use the other controller but the thing is that if someone is going to attend the party then part must be preschedule, mean when can not say because someone is going to attend the party thats why we orginized the party. 

Party should be there then only a person will go to attend .. mean we have have an entry before we are going to create an entry in system_user

Comment: let me give u another example.. - consider a sales order which always depends upon part.. right??                   then we must have a part in part table earlier to create the sales order.    I hope it can clear a pic.

Comment: Yes I understand what foreign keys are and how they make relationships  with other tables, but my question is not what foreign keys are, my question is how to actually implement this in Yii.

Comment: i will say you should allow the user to create the record only if we have corresponding record in party and party_type table. or you should not merge the system_user record with party controller, its prerequisite for the system_user controller.

Answer (score 1):

You have to implement a multi-step form and a single fatty controller which does all pluming working for you e.g adding/updating all three entities . please see this [thread](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/50196-multi-step-form/)